# Reverse Lat Long to Long Lat in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, geography

I have been given MYSQL spatial data in CSV format. The geometry field contains the Latitude and Longitude values but I need to swap it to Longitude and Latitude in that order, so I can view this in TSQL as well known text. Is this possible to convert?

e.g.

```
-38.24915 145.04892, -38.24912 145.0488, -38.24903 145.04883, -38.24906 145.04895
```

needs to be

```
145.04892 -38.24915, 145.0488 -38.24912, 145.04883 -38.24903, 145.04895 -38.24906
```

Thanks

Comment: You say "MySQL" but tagged with T-SQL, which is the MS SQL Server dialect of SQL. Please tag your question appropriately - which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For fun I put together a SQL Server 2017 solution. This may help you get you started.

```
DECLARE @yourstring varchar(1000) = 
  '-38.24915 145.04892, -38.24912 145.0488, -38.24903 145.04883, -38.24906 145.04895';

SELECT STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(item,11,100) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(item,1,10),', ')
FROM
(
  SELECT item = TRIM([value])
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@yourstring,',')
) split1;
```

**Returns:**

```
145.04892 -38.24915 , 145.0488 -38.24912 , 145.04883 -38.24903 , 145.04895 -38.24906
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING(item,1,9),', ')` appears to tuck the comma next to the `Lat`. Nice solution!

Comment: Thanks heaps, but the latest version we have is SQL Server 2016. Is there an alternative method for pre-2017 SQL?